# Strong loop studio with SQL Server

Tags: node.js, strongloop

I am trying to use strong loop studio to build an api for a SQL Server database. Almost all the functions are working but if I want to find after id like this `localhost:3000/api/tableName/1` where 1 is the id, I get a syntax error.

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'null'

Using SQL Server Profiler I got the query that is executed and I got this:

```
SELECT 
    [id], [name], [description], [application], 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        [id], [name], [description], [application], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (null) AS RowNum
     FROM [dbo].[tableName]) AS S
WHERE 
    S.RowNum > 0 AND S.RowNum <= 1
```

What could be the problem? Can I override this method in some way and rewrite the query? 
Actually i tried this on multiple tables and I get the same error.

Comment: What is your model definition? The MSSQL connector tries to run a SQL with pagination parameters and it seems that the id name is missing.

Answer (score 0):

That null comes from the order by clause in the SQL that StrongLoop creates. If it doesn't get an order, it seems to just use null. 
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mssql/blob/master/lib/mssql.js#L667

You can fix this by using an order in the default scope in your model.
http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-Defaultscope

```
  "scope": {
    "order": "id"
  },
```